# Passing arraylist of a class to another activity in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, arraylist

//This is my class

```
private String name;
private int height;
private float weight;
private int age;
private Sex gender;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public float getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public Sex getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public enum Sex {male, female, others}

;

public User(String name, Sex gender, int age, float weight, int height) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.height = height;
     }
}
```

This is from the 1st activity

```
ArrayList<User> userList  = new ArrayList<User>();
 Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileSelect.this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("list",userList);
        startActivity(intent);
```

And now I would like to display the userlist to another activity called mainactivity. How do I retrieve the list in the mainactivity?
Tq in advance..

Answer (score 0):

you can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

```
// Post Object
EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(yourObject);

// Get Object
YourClass yourObject = EventBus.getDefault().getStickyEvent(YourClass.class);
```